# Jquery Animate works randomly

Tags: php, jquery

Basically I have a shoutbox and new shouts are added to the bottom of the shoutbox.
I want each shout to scroll down animated.

Problem: It only Animates when it wants to.. Which is about every 10 shouts if your lucky..

Now I have tried applying .stop() and .dequeue()
A few other things to figure out why it randomly happens

Here is the code I am using..

```
function tbSingleScroll(){
if (tbscroll <= 0) {
    $('#shouts').animate({scrollTop: $('#shouts')[0].scrollHeight});
}
}
```

Now because it is a real time Shoutbox and set to update every 1 second to check for new shouts.
It also sets scroll to 1 second as well.
I have a countdown function that calls this function every second to scroll down.

Now so people could read previous shouts and scroll up I added a timer for 20 seconds
using this code

```
$("#shouts").scroll(function () { 
currentScrollTop = $("#shouts").scrollTop(); 

if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) {
    tbscroll = 20;
}
tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

Now is there a better way to set the scrolling?
Before applying this is was impossible to scroll up as it would just keep you locked to the bottom of the shoutbox because it was set to scroll down every second.
Now it detects that you have scrolled up and puts 20 seconds before it will call scroll down.

So I think its sending too many requests and just not doing anything.

Any help would be appreciated as to how I could fix this so I could have a nice effect on each incoming shout.
Also any help with getting the scrolling better would be nice..

Comment: I think a better way to do this is: If the ajax-script checking for new shouts returns true, then scroll as many new items as needed. Don't set scroll to 1 second. (Also, having the script to check every second can cause some serious overload).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion
I have moved the scroll to

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your shoutbox widget.
If it has an api, you could hook an event listener or a callback to the `new shout` event that would handle all your scrolling.
If it doesn't provide anything like an api or it's not thriggering any events, you should probably call a function that scrolls the shoutbox every **x** seconds.
Personally I think that you should stop the automate scrolling if a user is reading the shoutbox. I find it quite annoying to try to read something that randomly scrolls down. So my advice is to stop the scrolling when the user scrolls or focuses or clicks (depends on your shoutbox markup).
Here's what I have in mind :

```
$('#shouts').bind('scroll',function(e,data){
    //if the user has triggered it, we should stop the auto-scroll 
    if(data === undefined) 
        {
             clearInterval($('#shouts').data('scrollInterval'));
        }
});
var animationDuration = 1000; // 1 second
$('#shouts').data('scrollInterval',setInterval(function(){
    var shouts = $('#shouts').get(0);
    if(shouts.scrollTop < shouts.scrollHeight)
        return;
    $('#shouts')
        .stop()
        .animate({scrollTop: shouts.scrollHeight},animationDuration);
},1000));
```

Comment: Hey.. That is very useful information.

I have moved the call for the scroll function to

if(talk_jax.readyState == 4) {

It seems to be scrolling down on new shouts only now

There is no API its written in PHP and Javascript basically.
Flat file check to check for new shouts using refresh.txt to check for changed data then if changed get shout from MySQL database.

The only questions and problems I am having now is.. when navigating pages it scrolls to the bottom on page load then jumps around a lil leaving 2-3 shouts missing that you have to manually scroll down to read..

Comment: this is probably due to the fact that is scrolls down then the Shoutbox is still loading images and such around it that it jumps up..

Is there anyway to get this locked to the bottom..
This is one of the reasons I had scroll every 1 sec so that it would always be at the bottom.
ESP when changing pages..

With the code you written above.. Thank you very much for taking you time todo that.. Its most appreciated
I just have a question.. When will the talkbox start automatically scorlling down again?

Is there a way so that when they reach the bottom of the page it goes back into automated?

Comment: Sorry I would just like to add aswell that moving the call to the scroll function to if(talk_jax.readyState == 4) { 
Has solved my issue with .animate not working.. It is now working.
I just have a scrolling issue now stated above.

Comment: if you 're having problems with the container's size caused by images not being loaded, maybe you should preload the images in the shout and only after they are fully loaded shout the message. To do so, all you have to do is create a `new Image` object, attach a callback that shouts the message to it's `load` event and then set the `src` attribute correspondly.